# make tooltip follow mouse in dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tooltip, mouse

Is there a simple and performant way to make a tool tip follow the mouse cursor and have information that changes based on what part of a widget you hover. The reason I would like to do this is because I am making a flutter app for ordering pizza and I have a order pizza page where the user is asked to select the best time to get pizza. Currently it has a bar-like chart with a gradient of how busy it is (green means free and red means busy). I would like a toot tip that follows the cursor to appear when you hover on a day bar to show you information like what time it is that you are hovering on the day and a more detailed description of how busy it is. [image: order pizza view]

Comment: BTW: I use gentoo

Comment: did you try wraping with `Tooltip`

Comment: yes I did try wrapping the bar chart element with a tooltip but theres two issues with that

Comment: 1 the tooltip doesnt follow the mouse

Comment: 2 as far as I can tell You can't change the text in the tooltip depending on where on the bar chart elemnt your mouse is hovering eg if your hovering at the start of the tuesday bar the tooltip would see not busy but when you hover just before the end of the tuesday bar the tooltip would say busy. sorry for being slow at replying